# What's the `//2` in `:diffget //2`

Tags: vimdiff

I read "the //2 and //3 are unique identifiers for the target/master copy and the merge/branch copy file names" from [here](https://gist.github.com/mattratleph/4026987). Exactly what are those identifiers, and does `:diffget //2` work for 2-way diff at all?

Answer (score 2):

Whichever tool creating the buffer (fugitive etc), they do create buffername including "//2" for target buffer, and "//3" for merge buffer. Then we can use "//2" and "//3" as **bufspec** during merge.

As for 2-way diff (during amending or rebasing etc), there's one buffer with "//0" in its name. But in this case, the "//0" buffer could either be the buffer we want to copy the change to or from, depending on the scenario.